# Subject Identifier and ID Token/Userinfo Endpoint/Introspection Endpoint

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

As per the OpenId Connect specifications, the subject identifier returned in the ID token or from the Userinfo Endpoint may be [public or pairwise](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#SubjectIDTypes).
If it is a pairwise subject identifier, it is computed using the redirect Uri or the sector identifier Uri.

My questions are:

1. As there is no redirect uri in the [Userinfo request](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfoRequest), how is computed the pairwise subject identifier? Does it mean that the access token must contain the redirect Uri (or both public and pairwise subject identifier)?
2. Clients and Resource Servers may call the [introspection endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662). In the [Introspection Response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662#section-2.2), the resource servers should get the public subject identifier while clients are waiting the pairwise one. How can it be achieved. As well as the previous question, does it mean the access token must contain additional information to compute the subject identifier depending on who is calling the endpoint?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a client is either configured for public or for pairwise IDs, but not both at the same time (that would likely defeat the added privacy purpose of using pairwise IDs in the first place. Thus callers of any endpoint (whether UserInfo or introspection) would never see them mixed.

How does the Provider map the access token to a subject?

For classic opaque access tokens (i.e. a random string) the Provider simply keeps a lookup table from access token to the subject (pairwise or not, doesn't matter).

For structured (e.g. JWT) access tokens it could potentially look up the subject from the (verified) token itself indeed. But also in that case there is never a need to compute pairwise from public subjects (and the reverse isn't possible even), as the correct subject is always in the token.

Comment: Thanks. I agree with you. As the Id Token and the Userinfo Endpoint are dedicated to the client for authentication, there is no problem to serve the public or pairwise ID (depending on the client configuration). But concerning the Introspection Endpoint, I think the "sub" should not be included unless a resource server is sending the request (and in this case only the public ID should be included).